# How to configure Launchpad PPA to use build dependency from Backports repository?

Tags: package-management, ppa, launchpad

I want to build packages for my PPA using meson. I think I figured out how to do make a working recipe. However I need meson version (>= 0.4) which is not in the release repository of xenial.

However, in the backports repository (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meson) there is a meson with a version that is sufficient. How can I tell launchpad to build using the backports version? Is there some flag in the `debian/control` file I can use to tell launchpad to use the backported version?

For reference: my `debian/control` file:

```
Source: hardcode-tray
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Maintainer: ****
Build-Depends: build-essential, debhelper (>= 9), meson (>=0.40)
Standards-Version: 3.9.3
Homepage: ****

Package: hardcode-tray
Architecture: all
Depends: git, python3, python3-gi, wget, inkscape, python3-cairosvg, 
    gir1.2-rsvg-2.0, libqt4-svg, sni-qt, gir1.2-gtk-3.0, 
    ${misc:Depends}
Description: Fixes Hardcoded tray icons in Linux
```

the meson `Build-Depends` is giving me the issues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is a two ways to install a package:

- Install a package from backports and getting dependencies from a main
  repo

> apt-get install package/trusty-backports

- Install a package and all dependencies from backports repo

> apt-get install -t trusty-backports package

But if you still convinced that you should do it, here https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/BuildingASourcePackage is an instruction

> Depending on other PPAs
>   If you want Launchpad to satisfy your package dependencies using one or more other PPAs, follow the Edit dependencies link on your PPA or the team's overview page.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding a custom PPA to the PPA dependencies, you can also configure the Ubuntu sources that should be used (including backports), see screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh03t.png.

Comment: 2 things. 1. pictures of text are bad idea. 2. text should be in the body of the answer not as a pic.